# Set minimum date in date picker

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to set the minimum date in a date picker to today's date however I am getting the follwoing error

`ERROR TypeError: this.minDate.getFullYear is not a function`

Here is my code

TS

```
this.minDateValue = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'+'T00:00:00', 'en');

//this.minDateValue looks like this 2020-05-07T00:00:00
```

HTML

```
<p-calendar
formControlName="exitDate"
[defaultDate]=""
[yearNavigator]="true"
[minDate]="minDateValue"
dateFormat="d MM yy"
id="exitDate"
>
</p-calendar>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why don't you just use `new Date()`, without the `formatDate`?

Comment: @PoulKruijt that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `formatDate` is doing, but your errors seems to be that whatever that function is doing, isn't returning a valid `Date` object (since `.getFullYear` is not a function).

If you're trying to format a date, you should be using the `date` pipe in angular (https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

If you try setting `this.minDateValue` to `new Date()`, does it work? If you post your code for the `formatDate` function, it would help figure out why that isn't working for you.